# How to delete a membership report

Tags: civireport

I have copied an existing report template for my own use with the intention to use it for my search options. 
I don't understand how I can name it as I wish. How to rename a report when copying?
How to delete a copied report?

[![Screenprint:
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooPvy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooPvy.png)

Comment: you mention not seeing that tab - can you edit your question to tell us your CiviCRM version?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewing the report, click on the Title and Format tab to rename it, from the actions drop down menu you have an option to delete –

[image]

Further documentation on reporting can be found here -
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/reporting/set-up/

Comment: I don't see that tab on my screen!

Comment: what tabs do you see - have you checked Permissions